# link not inline because in it's own div?

Tags: css, hyperlink

The links were all horizontally aligned until i put one of them in it's own div to change it's color when i'm on the page it is linking to.

Now i can't get him to go back in line.

```
<div class="navigation">
  <a href="./productions.html">Mes productions</a>
  <a href="./DJ.html">DJ</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="./CV.pdf">Mon CV</a>
  <div id="contact">
    <a href="./contact.html">Me contacter</a>
  </div>
</div>

.navigation {
  padding: 40px 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navigation a {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px 35px;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: impact;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
}

#contact a {
  background: white !important;
  color: black !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `display: inline-block` on `#contact`, not `#contact a`.